# SWIG/Java: Object gets GCed too early

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm in the process of writing a Java wrapper around some C++ code with the use of SWIG. The bindings are working now, but unfortunately my objects that get created on the native side are free'd too quickly.

The code from bottom to top:

**C++:** [GitHub](https://github.com/jbaiter/kenlm-java/blob/master/src/main/c%2B%2B/lm/model.hh)

```
// ...
base::Model *LoadVirtual(const char *file_name, const Config &config = Config(),
                         ModelType if_arpa = PROBING);
// ...
```

**SWIG:** [GitHub](https://github.com/jbaiter/kenlm-java/blob/master/src/main/swig/KenLM.swg)

```
namespace lm::ngram {
    // ...
    lm::base::Model* LoadVirtual(const char *file_name,
                                 const lm::ngram::Config &config = lm::ngram::Config());
}
```

**Java:** [GitHub](https://github.com/jbaiter/kenlm-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jbaiter/kenlm/Model.java)

```
public class Model {
    private com.github.jbaiter.kenlm.jni.Model cModel;
    private String path;
    //...
    public Model(String path, Config config) throws ModelException {
        this.path = path;
        this.cModel = KenLM.LoadVirtual(path, config.getCConfig());
    }

    public long getOrder() {
        return this.cModel.Order();
    }
    //...
}
```

**Test Case with the Problem**: [GitHub](https://github.com/jbaiter/kenlm-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/jbaiter/kenlm/ModelTest.java)

```
@Test
public void getOrder() throws Exception {
    Model model = new Model(toy0Url.getPath());
    assertEquals(model.getOrder(), 3);
}
```

The test fails with a `NullPointerException` that is thrown because `model.cModel` is `null`. However, when I set a breakpoint in the `Model` constructor, the field is set correctly and `getOrder` returns the expected  result. As soon as the constructor's scope is left, though, **all fields** on my `Model` class are suddenly `null`. That `cModel` is `null` is probably due to my lack of understanding in regard to memory management with SWIG, but the fact that the `path`  field is `null` as well is really puzzling to me.

Comment: Try wrapping one of the types in your switch first. Does this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean :/ Which switch?

Comment: The source code of the LoadVirtual function. It has a switch. Can you create one of the objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause was actually a mistake in my Java code and had nothing to do with SWIG per se.
I had two constructors for the `Model` class, one of which called the other with `new Model(args)` instead of `this(args)`. This, of course, immediately discarded the properly initialized instance and left me with the un-initialized object (where everything is `null`).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably creating new object just to be used with Java side (there are no references to that object held on native side).
If its true, than you need to specify that this method creates new object that will follow java lifetime/gc

```
%newobject lm::base::Model* LoadVirtual(const char *file_name,
                             const lm::ngram::Config &config = lm::ngram::Config());
```

more about it you can found in swig documentation: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Customization.html#ownership

Comment: Thank you, that did not fix the error but is still very good to know :-)